# Specific AJAX request failing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

This one has been bugging me for a while. Hoping someone can help...

I have an ajax request as follows (this one works perfectly).

Controller:

```
def destroy
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @property_asset = @property.property_assets.find(params[:id])
    @property_asset.destroy

    property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @images = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('image')
    @videos = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('video')
    @docs = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('application')


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      flash[:notice] = "Deleted"
    end
  end
```

Destroy.js.haml:

```
$("#images").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'images')}");
$("#videos").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'videos')}");
$("#docs").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'docs')}");
```

This method, when called renders the partials on the page without needing to do refresh. Exactly what I want.

On the same page I have a file upload that calls a Create method:

```
 def create

    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @property_asset = @property.property_assets.create

    property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @images = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('image')
    @videos = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('video')
    @docs = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('application')

    if @property_asset.save
      if @property_asset.update(property_asset_params)
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js

           flash[:notice] = "File added"
         end
      end
    end 
 end
```

_create.js.haml is the same as the destroy file above but does not work with the any of the renders. So if I was to just try

```
$("#images").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'images')}");
```

The create method takes me to create.js.haml fine, I know if this because I can just enter a console.log and it spits out fine, but adding the line above and the console.log line fails and it doesnt render.

The images partial is:

```
- @images.each do |asset|
  = form_for [@property, asset], remote: true do |f|
    - if asset.id.present?
      .row
        .large-2.columns
          %ul.clearing-thumbs{"data-clearing" => ""}
            %li
              %a{href: asset.asset.url}
                %img{src: asset.asset(:thumb)}
        .large-10.columns
          .row
            .large-12.columns         
              = f.text_field :description, :placeholder => 'Description', :id => 'test1'
          .row
            .large-8.columns
              %p
                = f.check_box :private, :id => 'private'
                %label{for: "private"} Private
            .large-2.columns
              = f.submit 'Update', :class => 'button tiny right round', :disabled => '', :html => { :id => "update#{asset.id}" },  :remote => true
            .large-2.columns
              %p.right
                = link_to 'Delete', [@property, asset], method: :delete, :class => 'button tiny right round alert',  :remote => true
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. thanks.

**Logs**

This is when I just add in a simple console.log. JS console outputs fine. All ok.

```
(18.8ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered property_assets/create.js.haml (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4474ms (Views: 13.4ms | ActiveRecord: 169.5ms)
```

This is when I add

```
$("#images").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'images')}");
```

When the render is added log is:

```
  Rendered property_assets/_images.html.haml (19.0ms)
  Rendered property_assets/create.js.haml (23.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4017ms (Views: 34.7ms | ActiveRecord: 54.1ms)
```

The log before that is all the same, I'm adding a file into PropertyAsset using paperclip and I have papertrail tracking versions. When the render fails I need to refresh the page in order for the image to appear in the list.

Comment: Can you share your server output please? There could be some useful logging in there.

Comment: Thanks Alex, added - not sure it's much use though? Let me know if you need more...

Comment: Unrelated, but make sure you're not making unnnecessary SQL/DB calls around the assets re: `property.property_assets`. If it bangs on the DB for each, consider filtering on the Ruby side instead.

Comment: Are you sure the create method is working properly? I can't quite make out the indentation without an editor handy. Also, is it reasonable to set the flash where you do? Anything odd in the JS console?

Comment: Thanks Dave, will do. Apologies for indentation, but yep - create is being called. DB is being added to. If I refresh the page it works fine.

Comment: Are your flash notices working?  I thought you had to use a block with to have your `format.js` do work beyond rendering the template?  e.g. `format.js { flash[:notice] = "File added" }`

Comment: Yes flash shows up fine **IF** I don't render the images.js.haml.